# How to assign dlq config to lambda configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-lambda, config, amazon-sqs

After an event pattern is matched it will trigger the lambda function.
Under any failure scenario failed event payload is going into dlq we created.
I can manually select the dlq in aws console under asynchronous invocation but we need to add it in cloud-formation. what is the format to add. do i need to add in lambda.yaml and manifest.yaml
we are setting event retires under event bridge rule triggering the lambda function.

Architecture(Eventbridge->Lambda function->Dlq)

need a template to add those things in the cloud formation templates.

Answer (score 0):

In CloudForamtion there is [DeadLetterConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-deadletterconfig):

> A dead-letter queue configuration that specifies the queue or topic where Lambda sends asynchronous events when they fail processing.

Comment: Any sample template to add that in lambda.yaml and assign queue name in manifest.yaml